# Question regarding notation in Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a name for the set of functions $||f||_{C^{0, \alpha}}$? It's defined in my class as follows:

> $||f||_{C^{0, \alpha}}$ = $max_{x\in [0,1]}|f(x)|$ + $sup_{x,y\in [0,1], x\neq y}$ |$f(x) - f(y)$| / $|x - y|^\alpha$

(For $f\in C([0,1])$, some fixed $\alpha\in (0,1)$)

We're working also with the set $C^{0, \alpha}([0,1])$ = {$f\in C([0,1])$ : $||f||_{C^{0, \alpha}}$ <  +$\infty$}.

We need to find some $f\in C^{0, \alpha} ([0,1])$ such that $f\notin C^{1}([0,1])$. Does this simply mean that $f$ must either not be differentiable or that $f'$ is not continuous?

Comment: Functions in $C^{0,\alpha}$ are said to be $\alpha$-Hölder continuous.

Comment: @UmbertoP. thank you! I had not heard of that term until now.

Wikipedia is giving me that continuously differentiable functions are a member of $\alpha$-Hölder continuous functions - thus, do you think the question is emphasizing that the converse is not true?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Umberto P., these are the functions which are said to be Hölder continuous with exponent $\alpha$ or $\alpha$- Hölder continuous. The spaces $C^{0,\alpha}$ are different for different values of $\alpha$.

If $\alpha= 1 $ you get the space of Lipshitz continuous functions.

If $f$ is continuosly differentiable, then it will be Hölder continuos, but the converse need not be true (as can already be seen by looking at Lipshitz continuous functions, take $f(x) = |x|$ as an example).

Comment: This helps immensely - thank you so much!